# Changing feature id's of a layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, feature-id

How can I change the `feature id`'s of a layer using PyQGIS to an attribute value of that feature, where the attribute value is a unique integer? Is that possible at all, and if so, how?

Things like:

```
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print(feat.id())
    feat.id() = feat['myattr']
    layer.updateFeature(feat)
    print(feat.id())
```

seem not to be the way to do this. The layer is of type `memory`, so not physically stored on a harddrive.

---

Some background on why I want to do insane stuff like that:

Using PyQGIS I have a point-inputlayer having a `feature id` and this same `feature id` also as attribute value `fid`. Now I am running the processing algorithm `Voronoi Polygons` on it. Issue is, that these voronoi polygons will have a different `feature id` than the original corresponding input, but the same attribute `fid`. So on the voronoilayer, the attribute `fid` and the `feature id` are different, while they are the same on the pointlayer. Since I work a lot with spatial indizes in this script, which return the `feature id` instead of the feature itself I can no longer use `voronoilayer.getFeature(pointfeatureid_from_spatialindex)` to "re-"get the feature itself, but always need to use some more complicated stuff like:

```
pointfeat = pointlayer.getFeature(pointid_from_index)
myattr = pointfeat.id()
expression = QgsExpression( " \"{fieldname}\" = '{value}' ".format(fieldname='fid',value=myattr) )
request = QgsFeatureRequest(expression)
voronoifeat = voronoilayer.getFeatures(request)
voronoifeat = list(voronoifeat)[0]
```

Which makes things a little more complicated. So if possible I'd like to skip this and be able to use `voronoifeat = voronoilayer.getFeature(pointid_from_index)` directly.

**Is it possible to change the `feature id`'s of an existing layer or would I need to create a new layer and add the copied features from the old layer in my wanted order one after another?**

*While I (for now) accepted a good workaround on my actual issue, I am still interested in the actual answer to the question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you don't do a double mapping that enable you to match id from point layer to voronoi layer, like below? It's a purely Python approach that should be enough. It should do the equivalent of your wanted `voronoifeat = voronoilayer.getFeature(pointid_from_index)` ?

```py
mapping_id_voronoi = {f['fid']: f.id() for f in voronoilayer.getFeatures()}
mapping_id_point = {f.id(): f['fid'] for f in pointlayer.getFeatures()}

voronoilayer.getFeature(mapping_id_voronoi[mapping_id_point[pointid_from_index]])
```